# How to pass variable or wait for previous step execution in apache beam python

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have this pipeline:

```
from apache_beam import coders
from apache_beam.coders import RowCoder
from typing import NamedTuple
import apache_beam as beam
from fastavro.schema import load_schema
import typing
from apache_beam.transforms.sql import SqlTransform
from apache_beam.typehints import schemas
import json


def infer_schema(data):
    print(data)
    fields = [(key, str if type(value) == dict else type(value)) for key, value in data.items()]
    print(fields)
    global inferedSchema
    if len(inferedSchema._fields) == 0:
        inferedSchema = typing.NamedTuple('inferedSchema',
                                   fields)
        coders.registry.register_coder(inferedSchema, coders.RowCoder)
    return data

print("HI")
with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    record =( pipeline 
                     | "Read JSON" >> beam.io.ReadFromText("file2.json")
                      |"Infer schema" >> beam.Map(lambda x: infer_schema(json.loads(x)))
                      | "Transform to NamedTuple" >> beam.Map(lambda x: inferedSchema(**x)).with_output_types(inferedSchema) 
              # | "Transform to NamedTuple" >> beam.Map(lambda x: givenSchema(**x)).with_output_types(givenSchema) 
             #          | SqlTransform(
             # """
             #   SELECT
             #   *
             #   FROM PCOLLECTION""")
              | "Print" >> beam.Map(print)
            )
print(inferedSchema._fields)
print("Bye")
```

If I execute it withouth sqltransform it works perfectly well, it takes a dict (I need to use dict for my specific case and cannot use readfromJson) infers schema, and converts to namedtuple.

If I add sqltransform, then it seems to be skipping the schema and gives me empty results, unless I describe the schema (manualy) in the part before the pipeline. But then If Data changes it will not react to that.

Is there some wait function, or possibility to pass result, or wait for it, so I can infer schema from the first message?

Comment: You could try to use `side_input` for your schema: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/